# Как создать пользовательскую агрегатную функцию?

Tags: access, vba, ms-access

Подскажите, как создать функцию в модуле для групповых операций. Вот на подобие sum, только чтобы склеивались строки. Проблема не в логике, а в определении функции. Что она должна принимать? Я не могу найти определения для встроенных функций. Может, кто что знает об этом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я знаю, штатного интерфейса для создания пользовательских агрегатных функций нет. Можно использовать обходные пути для этого, типа передачи всего SQL в функцию, но скорость работы будет намного ниже, чем у штатных.
[Вот, например, топик на эту тему](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/writing-custom-aggregate-functions.3491184/)